# generic method ] extends multiple type parameter in JAVA

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

Im making a generic method which get an object and string.

it works at first like this..

```
public static <K, V> V getValue(Pair<K,V> _pair, String k){ ... }
```

I thought maybe it works as in main class

```
GrandChildPair<String, Integer> tst = new GrandChildPair<>("dd", 1);
Integer result = Util.getValue(tst,"dd");
```

But I wanna bound type extends to childPair not Grand one..
To limit this ..access? till ChildPair lines and not woking that in GrandChildPair.
so I've tried first in method definition,

```
public static <K extends ChildPair<K,V>, V extends ChildPair<K,V> V getValue (
```

but yes It was dumb so I've searched for maybe 3 hours about multiple type parameter extends in java but I couldn't found yet..
I found other single type pram extends examples but I could't find extend a whole
generic type (maybe not good at searching..)

Is there any I can do?

```
public class Util { 

    ///define method
    ////          //Type parameters //return type// method name ( prams...) {
    public static (Pair extends ChildPair) V getValue (Pair<K,V> _pair, String k) {

        if (k != _pair.getK())  return null; 
        else return _pair.getV(); 
    }
}

public class Pair<K, V> {
    private K k;
    private V v;

    Pair(K k, V v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public K getK() {
        return k;
    }
    public V getV() {
        return v;
    }
}

public class ChildPair<K, V> extends Pair<K, V> {
    public ChildPair(K k, V v) {
    super(k, v);
    }
}

public class GrandChildPair<K, V> extends ChildPair<K, V> {

    public GrandChildPair(K k, V v) {
        super(k, v);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<String, Integer> pair = new Pair<>("someone", 35);
        Integer age = Util.getValue(pair, "someone");
        System.out.println(age);

        ChildPair<String, Integer> childPair = new ChildPair<>("gh", 20);
        Integer childAge = Util.getValue(childPair, "sss");
        System.out.println(childAge);

    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you don't need any wildcard bounding fanciness. Just have your argument be `ChildPair<K,V>`.

Comment: I don't really understand your notation, Child < ChildPair means ChildPair extends Child or Child extends ChildPair?

Comment: Assuming you mean that `Pair` is a subclass of `ChildPair`, which is a subclass of `GrandChildPair`, and that you want method to require a `ChildPair`, then your method signature should be: `public static <K, V> V getValue(ChildPair<K,V> _pair, String k)`

Comment: @yshavit oh sorry for that.. yes as you guys pointed classes name is <K,V> end of those name

Comment: @Sweeper and yes ChildPair extends Pair in their definition

Comment: @Andreas yes Pair<K,V> works at first.. but then is it possible to work thru grandchildpair..?  so I just limit that method hava bound to ChildPair<K,V>

Comment: Are you trying to get it so that you can never pass a `GrandChildPair<K,V>` in? If so, the type system doesn't let you do that. It wouldn't make sense to, anyway, since people could easily get around it by doing `ChildPair<K,V> childPair = grandChildPair`, and then passing `childPair` in.

Comment: You're really confusing the issue with your weird inheritance syntax. In your code it says `Pair extends ChildPair`, but in your comment you say `ChildPair extends Pair`, and the syntax `Pair < ChildPair` is non-standard and hence means nothing to us, so which is it? Don't answer with a comment. Edit the question and **clarify** it, e.g. by showing declaration such as `class Pair<K, V> extends ChildPair<K, V>`.

Comment: ok... im trying..

Comment: Now that you've shown all the code, it seems you want to be able to call `Util.getValue()` with a `Pair`, so declare the method with a `Pair` parameter, i.e. `public static <K, V> V getValue(Pair<K, V> _pair, String k)`. Since `ChildPair` and `GrandChildPair` are both subclasses of `Pair`, the method can also be called with either of those. There is no way to prevent it from being called with `GrandChildPair`, if that was your question. If that wasn't your question, then I have no idea what you question is.

Comment: Do you want Pair and ChildPair to call Util.getValue(), but you don't want GrandChildPair to be able to call Util.getValue()?

Comment: @TimurA. yes its messy to me also after reading this again..

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Asking because knowing your real or higher goal we might be able to point to other avenues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** updated the check on what classes are not allowed based on *@OleV.V.*'s comment

I don't think you can **cleanly** force the method to not accept GrandChildPair as a parameter because java considers it as type of ChildPair and also Pair. I also think that if you have to do this then maybe these relationships have to be re-designed, because this is not the right way to go.

There is a not very good way to go:

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // works
            Pair<String, Integer> pair = new Pair<>("someone", 35);
            Integer age = (Integer) Util.getValue(pair, "someone");
            System.out.println(age);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            // mismatch in K so returns null
            ChildPair<String, Integer> childPair = new ChildPair<>("ch", 20);
            Integer childAge = (Integer) Util.getValue(childPair, "sss");
            System.out.println(childAge);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            // error
            GrandChildPair<String, Integer> grandChildPair = new GrandChildPair<>("gh", 40);
            Integer grandChildAge = (Integer) Util.getValue(grandChildPair, "gh");
            System.out.println(grandChildAge);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            // error
            OtherChildPair<String, Integer> otherChildPair = new OtherChildPair<>("oh", 60);
            Integer otherChildAge = (Integer) Util.getValue(otherChildPair, "oh");
            System.out.println(otherChildAge);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Util

```
public class Util {

    public static Object getValue(Pair<?, ?> _pair, String k) throws Exception {
        // check specific class and return / throw error
        // if (_pair instanceof GrandChildPair) {

        // OR check if it extends ChildPair and return / throw error
        if (_pair.getClass().isAssignableFrom(ChildPair.class) == false) {
            throw new Exception("call not allowed");
        }

        if (_pair.getK().equals(k) == false) {
            return null;
        }

        return _pair.getV(); 
    }
}
```

OtherChildPair

```
public class OtherChildPair<K, V> extends ChildPair<K, V> {

    public OtherChildPair(K k, V v) {
        super(k, v);
    }
}
```

Output

```
35
null
error: call not allowed
error: call not allowed
```

Comment: If you want to forbid *all* subclasses of `ChildPair`, I think you may use `if (!_pair.getClass().isAssignableFrom(ChildPair.class))` (or someting like it).

Comment: oh now I understand ole's comment now maybe I would little exceptional process with if statement thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few things you need to make it work. This is the right `getValue()`:

```
public static <K,V> V getValue (ChildPair<K,V> _pair, K k) {
    if (k != _pair.getK())  return null; 
    else return _pair.getV(); 
}
```

- You need to specify only two type parameters, `K` and `V` in the beginning: `static <K,V>`.
- The input parameter can be simply `ChildPair<K,V>` so it will accept `ChildPair` and `GrandChildPair`, however, it will reject `Pair`.
- I believe you want to make sure that the second param of `getValue()`, `k` will be always the same type as the `K` of the pair. Thus I specified it as `K k`. You can make it more flexible with `extends` : `public static <K,V,K2 extends K> V getValue (ChildPair<K,V> _pair, K2 k)`.

So this will be rejected, as designed:

```
Pair<String, Integer> pair = new Pair<>("someone", 35);
Integer age = Util.getValue(pair, "someone"); // compiler error
```

This will work:

```
ChildPair<String, Integer> childPair = new ChildPair<>("gh", 20);
Integer childAge = Util.getValue(childPair, "sss");
System.out.println(childAge);
```

This too:

```
ChildPair<String, Integer> grandChildPair = new GrandChildPair<>("gh", 20);
Integer childAge = Util.getValue(childPair, "sss");
System.out.println(childAge);
```

And this too:

```
GrandChildPair<String, Integer> grandChildPair = new GrandChildPair<>("gh", 20);
Integer childAge = Util.getValue(childPair, "sss");
System.out.println(childAge);
```

Comment: thanks its a little bit different but it's interesting flexible extending types and another bound way